# Capitalize the first character of all words (even when following a '-')

Tags: javascript, strings, regex

I got it working, all variations are displayed `Sint-Anna` as should be, but I wonder, is there a simpler way to this, since it looks very cluttered?

```
String.prototype.capitalize = function(){
    var sa = this.replace(/-/g,' ');
    var saa = sa.toLowerCase();
    var sb = saa.replace( /(^|\s)([a-z])/g , function(m,p1,p2){ return p1+p2.toUpperCase(); } );
    var sc = sb.replace(/\s+/g, '-');
    return sc;
};

console.log('sint-anna'.capitalize());
console.log('sint anna'.capitalize());
console.log('sint-Anna'.capitalize());
console.log('Sint Anna'.capitalize());
console.log('SiNt anna'.capitalize());
console.log('SINT ANNA'.capitalize());
```

Console:

```
Sint-Anna
Sint-Anna
Sint-Anna
Sint-Anna
Sint-Anna
Sint-Anna
```

There are no ways that there is a wrong input like `Si ntAn na` resulting in `Si-Ntan-Na`.

Comment: I know you said javascript, and I'm a bit late, but you could also use CSS for this if it fits your needs. `text-transform: capitalize` works exactly how you want it.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Your problem is an interesting one,but your solution is not a great use of regular expressions, since there's the better option of using the ['word boundary' anchor `\b`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#special-word-boundary).

The boundary anchor matches a transition from a word, to a non-word, or vice versa. For this purpose, using the [`\w` match to target word-characters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#special-word) after the `\b` is the right solution.

Note that the replace-function you give to the replace operation only needs the `m` argument now, there's no longer any sub-groups to process.

If your code was written as:

```
    String.prototype.capitalize = function(){
        return this.toLowerCase().replace( /\b\w/g, function (m) {
            return m.toUpperCase();
        });
    };
```

then you would convert-to-lowercase, then locate the first letter of any word, and convert that to uppercase.

Putting that in to action, like:

```html
<body>
    <input id="myInput" type="text" value="" size="50" />
  
    <pre id="myOutput" style="background-color:lightgrey">type something in the box above</pre>
  
    <script>
      
        String.prototype.capitalize = function(){
            return this.toLowerCase().replace( /\b\w/g, function (m) {
                return m.toUpperCase();
            });
        };
      
        var myInput = document.getElementById('myInput');
        var myOutput = document.getElementById('myOutput')

        myInput.addEventListener('input', function(e) {
            myOutput.innerHTML = this.value.capitalize();
        });
    </script>

</body>
```

Comment: I noticed that this will capitalize the first letter of a word that comes after a symbol but not after a number.  E.g.  `%asdf = %Asdf` but `3asdf = 3asdf`.  Not sure if that's a problem but thought I'd mention it.

Comment: It misbehaves for names like `Érica` (which it converts to `éRica`).

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel - yes, it does, and I am reminded that JavaScript does not have unicode support for RegExes... and it just plain sucks. I'm trying to figure out how to change it (the expression), but it will be ugly.

Comment: Try replacing `/\b\w/` by `/\b[\w\u00E0-\u00F6\u00F7-\u00FF]/` or `/\b[\wà-öø-ÿ]/`. You can check more UTF8 intervals here: http://www.utf8-chartable.de/unicode-utf8-table.pl?number=512

Comment: As a sidenote, you should change the `<input type="textarea">` to `<input type="text">`. And using inline events is a bad things now-a-days. Use an event listener which is a lot better. Even `field.oninput=function(){}` is better than an inline handler.

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel - good point about the textarea/text and the event. I confess I am guilty of hacking the stack snippet together without thinking too hard about anything other than the capitalization. About the unicode interval you suggest, unfortunately the problem is shared equaly between `\b` and `\w`. The `\b` needs to be changed to a negative-lookbehind in order to identify correct transitions, and that makes it harder than changing the \w.

Comment: Changing your regex with this `/(?:^|[^\wà-öø-ÿ])[\wà-öø-ÿ]/g` ugliness will work. This is REALLY UGLY, but it really works!

Answer (score -1):

The easiest way of making all the first letters uppercase in your array:

```
for (var i = 0 ; i < yourArray.length ; i++) {
    curTokens[i] = yourArray[i].charAt(0).toUpperCase()+yourArray[i].substr(1);
}
console.log(yourArray);
```

Every first character is taken using the `charAt(0)` and changed to uppercase using `.toUpperCase()`. We append the rest of the string using `yourArray.substr(1);`.